# How to turn off facebook app warning words

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
You must upgrade this app to Graph API v2.x
v1.0 將在 2015年4月30日過時
```

[image]

I already use php sdk 3.2.3, how come it still warning the version, is it must use 4.0.0? but my php version is 5.3, 4.0.0 required 5.4,

Comment: Did you follow the "Learn how to upgrade" link?

Comment: No you don't need to use 4.0.0. But you need to change your API calls to v2.0 or later

Comment: Yup I read it, but I don't know what should I do except use new sdk, I just use login function by PHP, I can't find anything to do with version, this is all my code

http://pastebin.com/4DLUw9BL

Comment: Dear @WizKid , May I ask how to login by calling API v2.0?

Comment: You add v2.0 or later in the url